# Java split not working consistently

Tags: java, arraylist, nmea

I have the following code below the output.

My issue is that the split function is not working correctly/consistently. 
I want to split on each "$". 
Reason being is that I want to parse the GGA and RMC data. 
Before anyone spends to much time, is this the right way to do this? 
My steps:
Read GPS data
Store sentence type (GGA, RMC) in variables that only store the most recent data
Parse those variables and pass to program and then database?

[
$GPGSV,,,,,,,,,*43

$GPRMC,055106.000,A,,N,,W,0.00,61.40,,,,A*4D]

[
$GPVTG,,,,,,T,,M,,,,K,A*3E

$GPGGA,055107.000,,N,,W,,,,M,-33.3,M,,0000*6T

$GPGLL,,N,,W,055107.000,A,A*44]

[

$GPRMC,055107.000,A,,N,,W,0.00,,,,,A*4F

$GPVTG,,,,,,T,,M,0.00,,0.0,,A*3E]

[

$GPGGA,055108.000,3,N,,W,1,09,0.9,,,M,,0000*62]

```
import jssc.SerialPort; 
import jssc.SerialPortEvent; 
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener; import jssc.SerialPortException;
import java.util.Arrays;
//import java.awt.List;
//import java.util.Base64;
//import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
//import java.io.InputStream;
//import java.io.InputStreamReader;
//import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
//import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
//import java.util.List;
//import java.util.stream.Collectors;
//import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;


public class test {
static List<String> datat = new ArrayList<String>();
static SerialPort serialPort;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1"); 
    try {
        serialPort.openPort();//Open ports
        serialPort.setParams(4800, 8, 1, 0);//Set params
      int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR + SerialPort.MASK_CTS + SerialPort.MASK_DSR;//Prepare mask
       serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);//Set mask
       serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader());//Add SerialPortEventListener


    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

/*
 * In this class must implement the method serialEvent, through it we learn about 
 * events that happened to our port. But we will not report on all events but only 
 * those that we put in the mask. In this case the arrival of the data and change the 
 * status lines CTS and DSR
 */

static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    //   if(event.isRXCHAR()){//If data is available
      //     if(event.getEventValue() < 577){//Check bytes count in the input buffer
                //Read data, if 10 bytes available 

                try {
                    String getdata =  serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue()+1);
                String[] parts= getdata.split("$");

                if(!datat.isEmpty()){
                    datat.set(datat.size() - 1, datat.get(datat.size() - 1) + parts[0]);
                }
                //data.set(data.size() - 1, data.get(data.size() - 1) + parts[0]);
                for (int i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {
                    datat.add(parts[i]);
               //     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
                }

               String[] data2 = datat.toArray(new String[0]);

               for(String s : data2) 
               {

                   data2 = s.split("$");

                   List<String> data3 = Arrays.asList(data2);
                 //  int testing = data3.size();
                   System.out.println(data3);


               }




                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {                  
             }

       }        
}


}
```

Comment: $ is a special character in regex. I believe you need the pattern \\$. USe str.split("\\$");

Answer (score 4):

The split function takes a regular expression, not a string, You are using a special character in a regular expresion ($) then you need to scape that character

```
String s= "$........$...$....";
String[] data2= s.split("\\$");
```

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't work properly. It prints without the $ sign which I need to keep and prints .s inbetween each character

Comment: that's how split method works, if you do a split with a withespace the result will be removed from the result array... you can make a method that reassembles the original string